# UWP and FullTrustProcessLauncher missing in namaspeace

Tags: powershell, uwp

I am trying to launch powershell (some lightweight commands that all user can do) command from UWP application using `FullTrustProcessLauncher`.

Problem is I am getting that this name does not exists in current context.

My manifest is largly default so it looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"

  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" 
  xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"

  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">

 <Dependencies>
   <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
 </Dependencies>

 <Resources>
   <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
 </Resources>

 <Applications>
   <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="PrototypeProject.App">

     <Extensions>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="powershell.exe">
      <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
        <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="TestGroup" Parameters="ls"/>
      </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
    </desktop:Extension>
  </Extensions>

   </Application>
 </Applications>

 <Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />

   <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>

  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

And class I am trying to call it from looks like:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Foundation;

namespace FullTrustProcess
{
    public class Ftp
    {
        public const string FtpParamGroupId = "TestGroup";

        public void RunFtp()
        {
            IAsyncAction operation = FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync(FtpParamGroupId);
        }
    }
}
```

Now am I missing something??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was missing - Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP, in extensions reference

Comment: I know, but SO will give me this opportunity to do this tomorrow :) that are the limits :)